# io.BytesIO when using python requests redirect-to

Tags: python, http, python-requests, pytest

I am trying to send a binary file through python requests library.
Here is the test code from python requests library:

```
def test_HTTP_307_ALLOW_REDIRECT_POST_WITH_SEEKABLE(self, httpbin):
    byte_str = b"test"
    r = requests.post(
        httpbin("redirect-to"),
        data=io.BytesIO(byte_str),
        params={"url": "post", "status_code": 307},
    )
    assert r.status_code == 200
    assert r.history[0].status_code == 307
    assert r.history[0].is_redirect
    assert r.json()["data"] == byte_str.decode("utf-8")
```

However, I could not pass the fourth assertion because the pointer of data was pointing to the end of data when it was trying to redirect to the final destination.

I tried to break the redirection into two, but handling it manually won't have history in r. I wonder how to fix this test case.
Any help would be appreciated!!